# Set Cookie File Name

Tags: javascript, cookies

How to set a cookie file name as `cookie:example@example.com` using java script?

I tried the following code

```
       document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value +";Domain: "+dom+";Path/" +path+"\n";
setCookie("username",username,365,"Cookie:example@example.com","/location");
```

But the file name takes the default working folder name.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You can't decide what filename a cookie should have when it's saved, that's up to the browser. The only think you can do with them is storing information and reading it later again.

Comment: My pleasure. =) I created an answer now, so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide what file name a cookie should have when it's saved, that's up to the browser.

The only thing you can do with cookies is storing information in them and reading it later again.